# Repetition of Argument Definitions in Roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a package with an S4 object and 10 functions which have the same 10 arguments. I can either just write the same @param for 10 times (as I currently do), or maybe I can just write them once with Roxygen2 in a documentation file. But I'm not sure whether it's feasible. I've seen another question on stackoverflow asking this, and it suggests a possible way of dealing with this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339247/how-to-document-multiple-arguments-at-once-with-roxygen2]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So just follow the other question instead of asking the same thing again.

Comment: How about `@inheritParams`?

Comment: Oh sorry for asking the same thing again! Won't do next time, Chris. And also, `@inheritParams` looks really good! I'll also try `@template`. Thanks Hadley!